# Rails ActionCable "connected" method not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, coffeescript, actioncable

I'm trying to use ActionCable in my Rails project, and while it seems that the WebSocket connection is being established no messages are being sent (only pings).

As far as I can tell the `connected` method in my CoffeeScript is never called.

This is my channel definition:

```
# app\channels\quiz_data_channel.rb:
class QuizDataChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "quiz_data"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
```

This is my coffeescript:

```
#app\assets\javascripts\channels\quiz_data.coffee:
App.quiz_data = App.cable.subscriptions.create "QuizDataChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
    console.log "[AC] on click handler called?"
    $('btn btn-primary btn-lg').on 'click', console.log "[AC] on click handler called!"


  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    # Called when there's incoming data on the WebSocket for this channel
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

This is my first rails project and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your `quiz_data.coffee`, you have
`App.quiz_data = App.cable.subscriptions.create "QuizDataChannel"`. I believe that this is expecting `quiz_data_channel` in your `quiz_data_channel.rb`file; where you have defined `stream_from "quiz_data"`. Try changing this to `stream_from "quiz_data_channel"`. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: Yes thank you, changing that fixed it. I just didn't notice at first because I was looking in the windows console, not in the browsertools console >_<